# Console and form in one and data transfer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, console-application

There is a code represents Console Application where I've done new Thread for the form and displaying a CustomForm on our new thread, I've also tried some kind of data transfer but I haven't successed.

Program.cs code ...

```
class Program {
    public static CustomForm _customForm {
        get {
            return customForm;
        }
        set {
            customForm = value;
            customForm.Show();
        }
    }

    private static CustomForm customForm;
    /// <summary>
    /// Static method which constains all the magic for the console!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Declaring Thread for the FormThread.
        Thread formThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FormThread));
        // Fires out the work of the thread.
        formThread.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        // And console is still running?
        // Thread formThread is still running too, thats the reason bruh!
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static method which constains all the magic for the form!
    /// </summary>
    static void FormThread() {
        customForm.lbl.Text = "Yolo, it wurks!";
        Application.Run(new CustomForm());
    }
}
```

CustomForm.cs code ...

```
public partial class CustomForm : Form {
    public string lblText {
        get {
            return lbl.Text;
        }
        set {
            lbl.Text = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just initializer, something what we'll never understand.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the form is loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Program._customForm = this;
    }
}
```

The only thing I want to do is call the lbl's text property and set some value in a program.cs, not in the customform.cs

Sometimes form wont to show or the lbl in the form isn't changed.

Comment: Where are you initializing `customForm`?

Answer (score 1):

`customForm.lbl.Text = "Yolo, it wurks!";` executes before you are creating `CustomForm`.

Probably, you need to create your form in the main and pass it into `Application.Run(CustomForm);`

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Declaring Thread for the FormThread.
        Thread formThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FormThread));
        // Fires out the work of the thread.
        customForm = new CustomForm();
        formThread.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        // And console is still running?
        // Thread formThread is still running too, thats the reason bruh!
    }
```

Also, you can't change a control property from other threads. In order to change property from other thread use `Invoke` method.

```
 public partial class CustomForm : Form {
     public string lblText
        {
            get
            {
                return lbl.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                if (lbl.InvokeRequired)
                    lbl.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => lbl.Text = value));
                else
                    lbl.Text = value;
            }
        }

 }
```